# Vuex state is readonly

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3, vuex, tauri

I want to change a **Vuex State** with a computed function like in the documentation, but it didn't change and the console gives this error.

> [Vue warn]: Write operation failed: computed property "renameActive" is readonly.

Im working with the VueCLI in Tauri.js.

**Add new Tab Vue Component:**

```html
<template>
<div class="TabContainer flex_c_h flex_start gap1">
    <div class="tab grid_c">All</div>

    <Icons
        :customClass="'addTab'"
        :icon="'plus'"
        @triggered="AddTab" />
    <RenameField v-if="renameActive" />
</div>
</template>

<script>
import Icons from '@/components/Assets/Icons.vue'
import RenameField from '@/components/Popups/RenameField.vue'
export default {
    components: {
        Icons,
        RenameField
    },
    computed: {
        renameActive() {
            return this.$store.state.renameActive
        }
    },
    methods: {
        AddTab() {
            this.renameActive = true
        }
    }

}
</script>

<style lang="">

</style>
```

**src/store/index.js**

```js
import { createStore } from 'vuex'

export default createStore({
  state: {
    navbar: [
      "upload", "folder", "reset", "settings", "about"
    ],
    currentTab: "All",
    renameActive: false,
  },
  getters: {
  },
  mutations: {
  },
  actions: {
  },
  modules: {
  }
})
```

**src/main.js**

```js
import { createApp } from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'
import router from './router'
import store from './store'

createApp(App).use(store).use(router).mount('#app')
```

How I can make it writeable?

Comment: correct `computed: { renameActive()` is readOnly - this hasn't anything to do with the store - perhaps you meant `this.$store.state.renameActive = true`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create mutation in your vuex store

```
 mutateActive: (state, val) => (state.renameActive = val),
```

and vuex action that you will call:

```
 setActive({ commit }, val) {
   commit('mutateActive', val);
 },
```

and in your method call vuex action and pass the value:

```
addTab() {
   this.$store.dispatch('setActive', true)
}
```

Comment: Mutations work. Thanks for the answer 

But before I was using all the time computed, because it's faster and less code for some smaller variables that are used in only 1 or 2 components. Do you maybe know what causes the read-only issue? Is it something that I need to change in the vue.config or in the main.js?

Comment: @Marcus Harting hey mate computed properties are read only

Comment: Actually, you can have writable computed too: https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/computed.html#writable-computed @MarcusHarting